# The cause of the error in pentaho kettle

Tags: kettle

In Pentaho kettle while execution the job I get below message repetetly:

> 13/03/01 15:12:47 - testing - Start of job execution
>    2013/03/01 15:12:47 - Transformation metadata - The shared object fie [null] is empty!
>    2013/03/01 15:12:47 - Transformation metadata - The shared object fie [null] is empty!
>    2013/03/01 15:12:47 - Transformation metadata - The shared object fie [null] is empty!
>    2013/03/01 15:12:47 - Transformation metadata - The shared object fie [null] is empty!

But the job is still running

Comment: Please provide more information. You have not included enough details to help us identify the problem.

Comment: I see this message frequently and it doesn't seem to hurt anything. It seems it can safely be ignored.